# MySQL - Can't update multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Whenver i try to update my columms in a selected row from PHP, it passed through without error, but it doesn't update in the database.

```
$query = "UPDATE news SET title = '$title', 
                  cover = '$cover', desc = '$newz', category = '$category' 
        WHERE id = $newz_select_id";
```

Comment: Does a simple `SELECT` or `INSERT` query work? Also you should know that your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) if any of the variables are obtained from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is a **[reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**. Escape it with backtick ( ` ) instead.

```
$query = "UPDATE news SET title = '$title', 
              cover = '$cover', `desc` = '$newz', category = '$category' 
    WHERE id = $newz_select_id";
```

by the way, your code is very susceptible to sql injection. in order to avoid it, please study and use PHP PDO or PHP mySQLi Extensions.

[See this Link: Best way to prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much John, that's good to know. Btw it worked ;)